# how to generate an embed.FS?

Tags: go

I have a `embed.FS`, like:

```golang
//go:embed static
var embedStatic embed.FS
```

and I want to (at startup time) pass the files through a [minifier](https://github.com/tdewolff/minify). I want to be able to create an in-memory `fs.FS` with the same files available on `embedStatic`, but with their content minified.

I know there are external libraries (like Afero and MemFS), but I'd usually try to avoid adding dependencies.

I also know I can do this by creating a new interface and implementing all the methods that I care about (`Open` for `fs.FS`, `ReadDir`, etc...) by myself, but it seems like everything that I want to do is already done by embed.FS, except for the construction of the files.

My question is: is there a way to do this while re-using `embed.FS`? Can I create an `embed.FS` on the fly?

I [can see](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/embed/embed.go#L181) that `embed.FS` has a `files *[]file`, but it's obviously private. I wonder if there's a way to create a new type and tell Go to "pretend this was created properly and just use it as an embed.FS".

Comment: No is a too short answer, but No.

Comment: Alternate solution to the problem: [Minify](https://github.com/tdewolff/minify/tree/master/cmd/minify) the source tree to a minified tree using [go generate](https://go.dev/blog/generate).  Embed the minified tree.

Comment: What's wrong with io/fs? Embedding a folder structure, blind, is almost guaranteed to not be what you want anyway. It certainly takes that compile-time guarantee and throws it out the window. Do you want to read from the filesystem? Use the io/fs package for that. Do you want to package up resources for a single-file deployment, and you're willing to give up any form of local mutability? Sure...but listen to @Zombo.

Comment: I'm not sure why "embedding a folder structure is almost guaranteed to not be what you want". Isn't this exactly what go:embed is for? But yeah, I'm trying to keep a single-file deployment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`embed.FS` is a specific implementation for reading files embedded in the binary - it can't be used for filesystems built at runtime.

There are some `fs.FS` implementations in the standard library that may work for your use case. You could process your files into:

1. A temporary filesystem directory and pass to [`os.DirFS`](https://pkg.go.dev/os#DirFS).
2. An in-memory ZIP file and use [`archive/zip.Reader`](https://pkg.go.dev/archive/zip#Reader) as an `fs.FS`.
3. [`testing/fstest.MapFS`](https://pkg.go.dev/testing/fstest#MapFS). This is really intended for testing, but it is there..

Personally, I'd would either:

- Minify via `go generate` before building the binary and using `embed.FS`. This could provide a smaller binary with less startup time/memory usage.
- Write my own `fs.FS` or pull in a dependency if the files need to be modified at runtime. It's not much code.